# Demo Framework versioning issue

Tags: 8, configuration, composer

Is the Demo Framework project not compatible with Composer 2.0? Are there any workarounds?

The output of `composer create-project acquia/df-project DemoFramework -s dev` is the following one.

> Creating a "acquia/df-project" project at "./DemoFramework"
> Installing acquia/df-project (dev-8.x-4.x 078c5f127d485581ce056a71e5ff98b5b2518717)
>
> - Syncing acquia/df-project (dev-8.x-4.x 078c5f1) into cache
> - Installing acquia/df-project (dev-8.x-4.x 078c5f1): Cloning 078c5f127d from cache
>   Created project in /var/www/html/drupal/DemoFramework
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - acquia/df[4.0.2, ..., 4.1.1] require cweagans/composer-patches 1.6.6 -> satisfiable by cweagans/composer-patches[1.6.6].
> - cweagans/composer-patches 1.6.6 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
> - Root composer.json requires acquia/df ^4.0.2 -> satisfiable by acquia/df[4.0.2, ..., 4.1.1].
>
> You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The error message tells you what to do: _Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2._ It means you need to check if there is a version of *cweagans/composer-patches* that works with Composer 2.0; if there isn't, report the plugin isn't compatible with Composer 2.0 in the issue queue for that plugin. (I am sure it has been already reported, if the plugin doesn't have a version compatible with Composer 2.0.)

Comment: Remember Newbie - How do I check for a correct version? And if there is what do I need to do to incorporate it?

Comment: You need to check the project page on Drupal or their git repository. If there isn't a version that works with Composer 2, you can try to create a specific environment for it where composer 1 is installed e.g. a docker container, a vagrant VM